# How to specify directories in sbt-uglify options

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, uglifyjs, sbt-web

I have a project based on play framework.
I'm using sbt-uglify plugin to minify & concatenate the js files

In my build.sbt I have defined

```
UglifyKeys.uglifyOps := { js =>
  Seq((js.sortBy(_._2), "javascripts/all.min.js"))
}
```

The above code includes all the js files.
However I want to do something like

```
UglifyKeys.uglifyOps := { js =>
  Seq(include all js only from controllers folder, "javascripts/controllers.min.js"))
  Seq(include all js only from services folder, "javascripts/services.min.js"))
}
```

How can I do this without using sbt-concat?

Comment: Did you find your answer? I have this problem too